# In PHP, How would I use a variable that was created in another php page?

Tags: php

I have an included page to the main index page, in the included page it has buttons to click on..i want to give these buttons a variable and when someone clicks on it, I can keep track of what button they selected in another page, which will show information for the selected button/variable...

Any ideas?

Comment: are you attempting to past a variable from one page to another?

Comment: Several people have suggested reading some PHP beginners' tutorials. I agree with that, but I would caution you that a lot of the PHP tutorials on the web are out of date and teach obsolete techniques. Make sure you learn from reputable and recently written sources.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is several ways to do this, but the main question is are you using a form button or a image button or a link or what?

**Form:**

HTML:

```
<form name="phpForm" action="myFile.php" method="get">
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="1">
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="2">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?PHP 
  echo $_GET["button"]; //either 1 or 2
?>
```

**Image:**

HTML:

```
<a href="myFile.php?button=1"><img src="whoo.png" /></a>
<a href="myFile.php?button=2"><img src="hilarious.png" /></a>
```

And the PHP above will also work with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should really start reading a basic PHP tutorial.

Depending on what form is the method, you'll receive the variables in either `$_POST` or `$_GET`:

Use this code to find out

```
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this you can either use GET, POST, or store the variable in a SESSION

I am assuming when user clicks the button it is directed to another page, if its true, then you can do a GET with `http://yoursite.com/pageTo.php?data='hello'` as the href that links to the button.  Where pageTo.php would `$_GET['data']`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to web programming, this should get you started: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp

Comment: @Byron ohhh sorry about that!! LOL, didn't get that one! Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Insert the jquery code to try out the click counts:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var count =0;
      $('button').click(function(){
          count = count +1;
         $('#showcount').html('click count' + count);
             return false;
     });
});
```

and somewhere in your body make a div with id = ' showcount' to show the click counts.
Or you can then save the click count into a text file to look at...or whatever
I hope this give you some ideas...